# using raphael.js in a spine.js application - module raphael not found

Tags: spine.js

Hoping someone can help here...

I'm trying to use raphaeljs in a spine app but I can't seem to get it to load the module.

Ive done the following:

- installed node and npm
- created an app using spine.app
- added raphael to package.json and slug.json
- added Raphael = require('raphael') to my controller
- run npm install .

I can see npm has installed the raphael node module under 'node_modules', but when I load the app, I'm getting 'uncaught exception: module raphael not found'

Hopefully I'm just missing something stupid - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Thanks Tom Cully - turned out all I needed was to require raphael/raphael